# blogdown::serve:site() error: Failed to launch site

Tags: r, blogdown

I am trying to preview the site but it does not work.

```
> blogdown::serve_site()
Launching the server via the command:
  /home/ankaae/.local/share/Hugo/0.91.2/hugo server --bind 127.0.0.1 -p 4321 --themesDir themes -t starter-academic -D -F --navigateToChanged
Error: Failed to launch the site preview in 30 seconds. Try to give it more time via the global option "blogdown.server.timeout", e.g., options(blogdown.server.timeout = 600).`
```

When I use build site instead it works fine but I can't preview the site.

```
    > blogdown::build_site()
Start building sites … 
hugo v0.91.2-1798BD3F+extended linux/amd64 BuildDate=2021-12-23T15:33:34Z VendorInfo=gohugoio

                   | EN   
-------------------+------
  Pages            | 141  
  Paginator pages  |   5  
  Non-page files   | 891  
  Static files     |  69  
  Processed images |  66  
  Aliases          |  11  
  Sitemaps         |   1  
  Cleaned          |   0  

Total in 3696 ms
```

I've tried googling around this morning but can't find anything out there. Does anyone have tips on how to proceed? I have updated all my packages etc.

Comment: > renv::diagnostics()
Diagnostics Report [renv 0.14.0]

# Session Info
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: this is the code https://github.com/trustIndex-togge/metalab.git

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to reproduce your problem (on macOS). From your renv.lock, at least your blogdown version is not the latest: https://github.com/trustIndex-togge/metalab/blob/0b029c881865cc9fca52b2126faf355790db697f/renv.lock#L123

Comment: I manage to solve the problem the other day by removing the server URL in r.proj file and can now host it locally. Thanks for your help anyway :)